# Sql Join Query with three tables

Tags: sql, join

Table1

```
HospitalID   HospitalName                     Address
    1        Andalusia Regional Hospital      Andaluisa
    2        Baypointe Hospital               New York
    3        Axa Hospital                     California
```

Table2

```
ID   HospitalID   ClinicName
 1     1          Women Health
 2     1          Man Health
 3     1          Travel Health
 4     1         Cardiology
 5     2         internal medicine
 6     3         Cardiology
```

Table3

```
Id  HospitalID  TargetHospitalID  DistanceKm
 1      1              2           45
 2      1              3           95
 3      2              3           15
```

I am on the HospitalID=1 Hospital.(in cardiology)

I need to find the closest hospital from here with  my hospital  id.

```
select top 1 TargetHospitalID 
from Table3 
where HospitalID = 1 
order by DistanceKm
```

This code results TargetHospitalID=2. But, no cardiology department at Baypointe Hospital.

I need to find the nearest hospital with a cardiology department. How to do this query? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without a server side script, I am unsure how you are going to present the results or perform the query. Please provide more code example of what you're doing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your query joining it with the Table2 and filtering by the department.

```
select top 1 t3.TargetHospitalID 
from Table3 t3 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t3.TargetHospitalID = t2.HospitalID
where t3.HospitalID=1 and t2.ClinicName = 'Cardiology'
order by t3.DistanceKm
```